# Django form rendering: How can I wrap checkbox input and its label within a div?

Tags: html, django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

In a **django** form, How can I wrap an input and its label?

I have **django** form with a **BooleanField**. That field renders like this:

```
<div id="..." class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="">
  <input type="checkbox"....>
  <label for="...."....>

  <div> help_text <div>
</div>
```

I want to wrap the input and the label but not the help text:

I want something like:

```
<div id="..." class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="">
  <div id="wrapper_div">
    <input type="checkbox"....>
    <label for="...."....>
  </div>
  <div> help_text <div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you use form.as_table?

Comment: no, I'm using {% crispy form %}

Comment: i don't know how to customize crispy forms but you can custimize forms without using crispy you can [check this page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/?from=olddocs#rendering-fields-manually)